# Solving a large system of equations using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to solved a system of equations that results from estimating a 4th order differential equation. To do this requires creating a large matrix (A), usually 105 x 105, taking the inverse and multiplying by a 105 x 1 matrix (B). To do this, I'm using the linear algebra approach solving Ax = B.

Running the following code:

```
Dim A(1 To 105, 1 To 105) As Double
Dim B(1 To 105) As Double
Dim i As Integer

' Used to make sure all values of A are initialized to zero 
For i = 1 To 105
    For j = 1 To 105
        A(i, j) = 0
    Next
Next

For i = 1 To 105
    A(i, i) = EI
    A(i, i + 1) = -4 * EI + axial * h ^ 2
    A(i, i + 2) = 6 * EI - 2 * axial * h ^ 2 + km(i) * h ^ 4
    A(i, i + 3) = -4 * EI + axial * h ^ 2
    A(i, i + 4) = EI

B(i) = W * h ^ 4

Next
Dim x(1 To 105) As Variant
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult((Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(A)), B)
```

results in "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the MInverse property of the WorksheetFunction class"

I've explored this error and it appears that it means I'm passing bad data to the function either text or blank values so I added the two loops at the top to initialize matrix A to 0 however this did nothing. After exploring some more I found some obscure post about a maximum size of matrices being 52 x 52 but wasn't able to find any more information about this.

Comment: The 52 x 52 limitation was lifted in version 2007 i believe but large matrices are often near-singular which i'd guess to be the issue here. Instead try searching for methods to invert sparse matrices which can be more efficient and accurate for this type of problem. Also note that the last argument in the code needs transposing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit of 52 x 52, as mentioned in the official documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.minverse.aspx

**EDIT**

The documentation seems to be wrong. I tested `=MINVERSE(A1:DA105)` and it works well.

Very likely your matrix contains numbers that generate very large numbers and it fails. I populated my matrix 105 rows with numbers from 1 to 105 and it was failing. Then I put `=RAND()` in all the cells and it worked.

If the large numbers are the problem, perhaps there are tricks like populating the matrix with the logarithm of the numbers. It's a trick I use in other cases, I don't know if it can be used with a matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I'll explore other methods of solving systems of equations.

Comment: @AndrewGulbronson Please remember to accept the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Interesting, I just ran the same test on my machine and it did not work. Thanks for the followup though!